# Flask Formsubmission Error

Tags: flask

I am trying to follow [This Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-flask-adding-a-contact-page--net-28982) to add forms to [my crappy site](http://www.davidterwilliger.com).  Progress is local, so the contact page on my site is broken.

Specifically, I am having trouble getting flask to recognize the post request.  Watching the debugger has given clues, errors below.  I followed the (linked about) tutorial, and was able to get it to work, I'm attempting to move a similar idea to my site, this is not working.

Watching the debugger, I go to the contact page, fill in the form and hit submit.  The get works, the post does not.

Log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2015 22:11:47] "GET /contact HTTP/1.1" 200 -  
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2015 22:11:50] "POST /mail/contact_me.php HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I have no idea what /mail/contact_me.php is, I have no such named file or folder for that matter.

A major clue (which makes no sense to me) is that removing the template inheritance from this contact.html allows the form to work.

The original (non-functional) contact.html is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Contact</h2>
<form action="{{ url_for('contact') }}" method=post>
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}

{{ form.name.label }}
{{ form.name }}

{{ form.email.label }}
{{ form.email }}

{{ form.subject.label }}
{{ form.subject }}

{{ form.message.label }}
{{ form.message }}

{{ form.submit }}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Removing the templating (removal of the first two and last lines) allows the form to post correctly.  After removing, reloading the page and submitting the form I get the following logs in the debugger:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2015 22:43:46] "GET /contact HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Mar/2015 22:43:48] "POST /contact HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

it also now works, submission of the form returns the placeholder string.
It appears my template is somehow breaking the form, what do you think is causing this?

Other possibly relevant chunks of code.

routing file

```
.
.
@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
  form = ContactForm() 
  if request.method == 'POST':
    return 'Form posted.'

  elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
.
.
```

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import TextField, TextAreaField, SubmitField
class ContactForm(Form):
    name = TextField("Name")
    email = TextField("Email")
    subject = TextField("Subject")
    message = TextAreaField("Message")
    submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

A more complete example of my code is here, though recent changes-code above- haven't been pushed.  I need more reputation but its https:// github.com/terwilld/website

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found your error.  Your `clean-blog.min.js` file is intercepting your `Submit` event and `POSTING` to that bogus URI:

```
$(function () {
    $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: !0, submitError: function () {
        }, submitSuccess: function (a, b) {
            b.preventDefault();
            var c = $("input#name").val(), d = $("input#email").val(), e = $("input#phone").val(), f = $("textarea#message").val(), g = c;
            g.indexOf(" ") >= 0 && (g = c.split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ")), $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {name: c, phone: e, email: d, message: f},
```

Sounds like you need to re-think the usage of that JavaScript file.